# Can I impose licensing terms on the content that users create or transmit using my program?

Tags: software, licensing, terms-of-service

[This comment](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/101280/can-i-send-someone-an-email-that-they-are-not-licensed-to-download-or-copy?noredirect=1#comment237110_101280) about email client monoculture made me wonder if what the poster is describing is possible.

Say I write and distribute a piece of communications software, like Outlook or Trillian or one of those new-fangled apps for posting on different Mastodon servers. Can I impose a licensing obligation on my users, like "you must give the recipients of your message a license to copy it"?

Or, perhaps equivalently, imagine a version of Photoshop that always produces CC-BY images, because the user is obligated to attach those terms to the output.

If so, how would I do that? If not, why not?

Comment: I'd think you just need to write this into the TOS, no? That's what all the social media platforms do.

Comment: If that was the sort of thing you CAN do with TOS I would have expected some company to have done it.  [This question may be relevant](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/5478/is-the-output-of-an-open-source-program-licensed-the-same), though certainly not a duplicate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can the author of software claim copyright on the data it generates?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/14048/can-the-author-of-software-claim-copyright-on-the-data-it-generates)

Answer (score 1):

### Facebook ToS 2015-18

The Terms of Service of Facebook back in 2015 to 2018 containted language that automatically granted every user of Facebook a license to use the content of other uses that was published publicly. These terms are archived in court cases, [such as this one](https://www.courtlistener.com/docket/15790587/30/1/bradley-v-analytical-grammar-inc/), and found enforceable:

> 2. Sharing Your Content and Information
>
> You own all of the content and information you post on Facebook, and you can control how it is shared through your privacy and application settings. In addition:
>
> 1. For content that is covered by intellectual property rights, like photos and videos (IP content), *you specifically give us the following permission, subject to your
>    privacy and application settings: you grant us a **non-exclusive, transferable, sub-licensable, royalty-free, worldwide license** to use any IP content that you post on
>    or in connection with Facebook (IP License)*. This IP License ends when you delete your IP content or your account unless your content has been shared with
>    others, and they have not deleted it.
> 2. When you delete IP content, it is deleted in a manner similar to emptying the recycle bin on a computer. However, you understand that removed content may
>    persist in backup copies for a reasonable period of time (but will not be available to others).
> 3. When you use an application, the application may ask for your permission to access your content and information as well as content and information that others
>    have shared with you. We require applications to respect your privacy, and your agreement with that application will control how the application can use, store,
>    and transfer that content and information. (To learn more about Platform, including how you can control what information other people may share with
>    applications, read our Data Policy and Platform Page.)
> 4. **When you publish content or information using the Public setting, it means that you are allowing everyone**, including people off of Facebook, **to access and use
>    that information**, and to associate it with you (i.e., your name and profile picture).
> 5. We always appreciate your feedback or other suggestions about Facebook, but you understand that we may use your feedback or suggestions without any
>    obligation to compensate you for them (just as you have no obligation to offer them).